# MPMoviePlayerController iPhone Navigation Bar Problem

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a view controller which includes a MPMoviePlayer inside. I hide the navigation bar, and want it to be shown when the video paused.

When the video is loaded, it works just fine. After i paused the video navigation bar appears but it pushes the whole player view to a little bit down. How can i make navigation bar appear without affecting the player view.

here is the code i used:

In ViewDidLoad():

```
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(videoPlayerPlaybackStateChanged:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];

[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
//For viewing partially.....
moviePlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
//[moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 410)];
[moviePlayer.view setFrame:[self.view bounds]];
moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view]; 

[moviePlayer play];

- (void) videoPlayerPlaybackStateChanged:(NSNotification*) aNotification 
{
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];

if(player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused){

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

}
else if(player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying){
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}

[player autorelease];    
}
```

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your condition

```
if(player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused)
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

}

Try using

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
```